# MediaSource API - Safari pauses video on buffer underflow

Tags: google-chrome, safari, video-streaming, webkit, media-source

I am trying to stream low latency video to the browser using the [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). For context, I am receiving live H.264 video over a WebRTC data channel (with custom reliable delivery protocol), muxing into a fragmented MP4 container in the browser and feeding this data to the MediaSource API.

In this scenario I will often not have enough data to feed to the API, either because: 1) no frames are sent from the server because nothing has visually changed, or 2) network hiccups cause data to be delayed.

In this "buffer underflow" case, I notice behaviour differences between Safari and Chrome:

Chrome will happily wait for more data to arrive and continue playing the video where it left off, maintaining a constant short buffer time between the `HTMLVideoElement.currentTime` and the end of the `SourceBuffer`.

Safari will pause the video element as soon as no more data is available and I must forcefully continue playing the video with `HTMLVideoElement.play`, and also update the `HTMLVideoElement.currentTime` back to near the end of the `SourceBuffer` end time. This causes noticeable hitches in the video playback.

Is there any way to achieve the behaviour seen in Chrome, in Safari? I think this might be related to "low delay" mode which is present in the MediaSource implementation for Chrome (which I believe is turned on after inferring information from the fed video stream) - is there a way to trigger something similar in Safari?

See repro code below. In this case I have already muxed the video into fragmented MP4, and I am feeding it into the MediaSource API using `setInterval` rather than over a WebRTC data channel, but the end result is the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="text">Click anywhere to start streaming video</p>
    <video autoplay playsinline id="video" width="800" height="450"></video>

    <script>
      /** @type HTMLVideoElement */
      const videoElement = document.getElementById('video');

      /** @type HTMLParagraphElement */
      const textElement = document.getElementById('text');

      async function start() {
        let fileReadPointer = 0;

        // Queue up video fragments to be appended to the SourceBuffer - we
        // can't append them immediately as we must wait until the SourceBuffer
        // has finished updating.
        let fragmentQueue = [];

        // File contents is fragmented MP4 (output from JMuxer) chunks.
        // Each chunk is prefixed with a 4-byte chunk length.
        const file = await fetch('video.dat');
        const fileBytes = await file.arrayBuffer();

        const CODEC_MIME_TYPE = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.424028"';

        // Create MediaSource
        const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleMediaSourceOpen);

        // Assign MediaSource to <video> element
        const mediaSourceUrl = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        videoElement.src = mediaSourceUrl;

        // Source buffer. We will create this later once the MediaSource has opened.
        let sourceBuffer;

        // Read next fragment from data file and append it to the fragment queue.
        function receiveNextFragment() {
          // Each fragment is stored as a 4-byte length header, followed by the
          // actual bytes in the fragment.
          if (fileReadPointer + 4 > fileBytes.byteLength) {
            return;
          }

          // Read length from data file
          const length = (new DataView(fileBytes)).getUint32(fileReadPointer);
          fileReadPointer += 4;

          // Read next bytes from data file
          const data = new Uint8Array(fileBytes, fileReadPointer, length);
          fileReadPointer += length;

          fragmentQueue.push(data);

          // Feed source buffer with the latest data if it's not already
          // updating.
          if (!sourceBuffer.updating) {
            feedSourceBufferFromQueue();
          }
        }

        function feedSourceBufferFromQueue() {
          if (fragmentQueue.length === 0) {
            return;
          }

          const nextData = fragmentQueue[0];
          fragmentQueue = fragmentQueue.slice(1);
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(nextData);
        }

        function handleMediaSourceOpen() {
          // Create source buffer
          sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(CODEC_MIME_TYPE);

          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', ev => {
            // If there is any more data waiting to be appended to the
            // SourceBuffer, append it now.
            feedSourceBufferFromQueue();
          });

          // Receive video fragments much more slowly than their duration, to
          // cause buffer underflow.
          //
          // Note that the video will continue to play on Chrome as
          // new frames are received, but will pause on Safari as soon as the
          // buffer runs out.
          setInterval(() => {
            receiveNextFragment();

            // Update browser text to reflect video paused state.
            textElement.innerText = `Video paused: ${videoElement.paused}`;
          }, 100);
        }
      };

      // Start once the user clicks in the document (to avoid autoplay video
      // issues)

      let started = false;

      function handleClick() {
        if (started) return;
        started = true;

        start();
      }

      document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    </script>

    <style>
      video {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer, which is to explicitly set the duration to +Inf on the `MediaSource` object once it has been opened:

```
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
    mediaSource.duration = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
});
```