# Video Stream Doesn't start in Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, html, ios, video, safari

I have a stream link `https://staging.wrkble.com/api/courses/7eb709ad-a68d-47e0-b28a-3b936c7dc10c/chapters/240ce029-936b-4184-9a4c-f235dc1368d7` that works out perfectly with chrome and Firefox browsers.

Running the following code with safari vs other browsers will make it self explanatory yet I will add on to what I have already tried before posting this question.

```html
<button id='cta'>CTA</button>
<video preload="metadata" id="video" class="video" type="video/mp4"
    src="https://staging.wrkble.com/api/courses/7eb709ad-a68d-47e0-b28a-3b936c7dc10c/chapters/240ce029-936b-4184-9a4c-f235dc1368d7"
    autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>
<script>
    document.getElementById('video').play();
</script>

<video preload="metadata"
    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a7/How_to_make_video.webm/How_to_make_video.webm.360p.webm"
    autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>


<video preload="metadata" type="video/mp4"
    src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" autoplay playsinline
    webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>

<style>
    video {
        width: 500px
    }

    @media (-webkit-video-playable-inline) {}
</style>
```

### List of things already tried

- Server configuration is fine,
  [image]
  [image]
- Range header returns requests bytes,

[image]

- use of playsinline, muted and autoplay
- Use of .play() as a script tag after the video tag
- These SO questions and Apple dev website:
  [Safari Buffer underflow SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74461792/mediasource-api-safari-pauses-video-on-buffer-underflow) ,
  [Apple configurations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6) , [HTML video first frame freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671723/chrome-and-safari-html5-video-rendering-hanging-on-first-frame) , [IOS Device HTML video tag safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347352/html5-video-tag-not-working-in-safari-iphone-and-ipad) , [Safari Server Configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168709/html-video-not-playing-in-safari-browser) , [Safari: Video plays in only other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712778/video-plays-in-other-browsers-but-not-safari/36299252#36299252) , [Video texture loading problem](https://forum.shapespark.com/t/safari-video-texture-loading-problem/2114) , [Range Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156306/html-5-video-tag-range-header) , [Delivering Video content for safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari/)

This was necessary to add so it doesn't get marked as a duplicate, the question is researched first and then posted.
Images (First one is my stream link)

[image]
[image]

I am attaching the running code which reproduces the problem:

```html
<button id='cta'>CTA</button>
<video preload="metadata" id="video" class="video" type="video/mp4"
    src="https://staging.wrkble.com/api/courses/7eb709ad-a68d-47e0-b28a-3b936c7dc10c/chapters/240ce029-936b-4184-9a4c-f235dc1368d7"
    autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>
<script>
    document.getElementById('video').play();
</script>

<video preload="metadata"
    src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/a/a7/How_to_make_video.webm/How_to_make_video.webm.360p.webm"
    autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>


<video preload="metadata" type="video/mp4"
    src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" autoplay playsinline
    webkit-playsinline loop muted controls></video>


<!-- <script>
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953639/the-mediaelement-play-method-returns-a-promise-that-is-rejected
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.addEventListener('durationchange', () => {
        this.currentTime = 10;
    }, false);
    let cta = document.querySelector('#cta');

    (function () {
        playMedia();
    })();
    async function playMedia() {
        try {
            await video.play();
        } catch (err) { }
    }

    cta.addEventListener('click', function () {
        video.play();
    });
    window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (event) => {
        console.log(event.reason);
    });
</script> -->

<style>
    video {
        width: 500px
    }

    @media (-webkit-video-playable-inline) {}
</style>
```